# Deploying .NET REST Services - Page Not Found - 404 Errors

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, http-status-code-404

I have a very simplistic REST service (.NET 3.5) somewhat based on the articles found at:

http://swindelles.com/2008/07/11/creating-rest-web-services-in-c-sharp/

- and -

http://swindelles.com/2008/07/22/creating-rest-web-services-in-c-sharp-2/

It works when I run it from within Visual Studio - in other words, by hosting it on localhost via Visual Studio's web server. However, when I use Visual Studio's "publish" to build and package the files for deployment, and then copy them over to my remote paid web host's server, I get 404 errors when I try to access the service.

I will post my code at the end.

Here is an example of a URL that works on localhost:

```
http://localhost:5077/MathHttpHandler/?num=5
```

(I know that by using the `?num=5` query string parameter, I'm kind of going against pure REST concepts, but that is a question I'll deal with later. I'm just trying to get this thing to work first.)

On my remote web host's server, I copied the "published" files over to a subdirectory directly beneath the root ("/dev"). Here are examples of URLs I have tried to use but only get 404 errors when I do so:

```
http://<my domain>.com/dev/MathHttpHandler
http://<my domain>.com/dev/MathHttpHandler/
http://<my domain>.com/dev/MathHttpHandler/5
http://<my domain>.com/dev/MathHttpHandler/num=5
http://<my domain>.com/dev/MathHttpHandler/?num=5
```

Here are the relevant files:

MathHttpHandler.cs:

```
using System.Web;

namespace RestSpike02Library {
    public class MathHttpHandler : RestHandlerBase {
        public static string QS_NUM = "num";

        public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
            //Call the base method to set up everything to default values first
            base.ProcessRequest(context);

            if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "GET") {
                int toSquare;
                if (int.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString[QS_NUM], out toSquare)) {
                    int squared = toSquare * toSquare;
                    context.Response.Write(squared.ToString());
                }
                else {
                    context.Response.Write("Invalid integer.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />

        <!-- For IIS6 and earlier -->
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="MathHttpHandler/*" type="RestSpike02Library.MathHttpHandler, RestSpike02Library"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <!-- For II7+ -->
        <handlers>
            <add name="MathHttpHandler" verb="*" path="MathHttpHandler/*" type="RestSpike02Library.MathHttpHandler, RestSpike02Library"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with my files? Is there something I should do on the server side (like some sort of configuration) to make this work?

It should be noted that I've had similar problems trying to get any kind of service working on the remote server (.ASMX, WCF, etc.).

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Do you know what version of IIS your remote service is actually running?

Comment: As far as I can tell, they're using IIS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone, for your suggestions. It turns out that there was something wrong with the way my host had the directories configured. They fixed the problem on their end but they haven't been able to tell me what the problem was or how they solved it. So, on one hand, I'm glad they fixed it, but on the other, I have no idea how to avoid this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you copy the files to a "subdirectory" - is it configured to run as an application?

Web.config files in subdirectories can't register HttpHandlers. This must occur in the root application config. You can register them there by nesting the `<system.web>` and `<system.webserver>` nodes inside of a `<location path="dev">` node.

Otherwise you can configure the subdirectory to run as an application and include the other required portions of the web.config.

Comment: Thank you, lukiffer. When you say "configure the subdirectory to run as an application", what do you mean, exactly? I have used my web host's IIS interface to set the subdirectory to an "applciation" (and also a "virtual directory". Is that what you mean?

Comment: I just tried moving the web.config to the root directory and I still get the same results.